# Why is Processing skipping frames

Tags: processing, graphics2d, frame-rate

This is a simple program in processing, all it does is draws four circles in the last four frames (My Graphics card's refresh rate is 60Hz, so it draws them once every second)

But sometimes for some reason it is skipping frames, so I don't see all the four circles. Why is that and what can I do to make it not skip frames.

```java
int counter = 1;

void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
  fill(255);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  if(counter == 57){
    ellipse(383,383,100,100);
  }
  else if(counter == 58){
    ellipse(583,383,100,100);
  }
  else if(counter == 59){
    ellipse(783,383,100,100);
  }
  else if(counter == 60){
    ellipse(983,383,100,100);
    counter = 0;
  }
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens each time the `draw()` function is called:

- First you call `background(0)` to clear out old frames.
- Then you check which frame it is, and possibly draw a circle.

What happens on frame 61? You're going to clear out the old frames (clearing out the circles you've drawn), and then not draw anything. So each circle is shown for 1/60th of a second, which is probably impossible for you to see.

To fix your problem, you need to think about what you want to happen each frame. Consider getting rid of the call to `background()` so old frames are not cleared out, or possible redrawing old circles every frame. It depends on exactly what you want your sketch to do.

Side note: you don't need to create your own `counter` variable. Processing provides a `frameCount` variable that does exactly this. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time but I did reset the counter every time I reach 60, so It's a loop. I can see the circles flashing even if it's there for a few frames. I believe it has something to do with VSync and I dont know about it which is why I've asked.

Comment: @Mark Even if you're resetting the counter, you're still clearing out old frames. It's not a VSync issue. You're clearing the circles out immediately after drawing them.